# What is the copper frame around this high speed input signal called?

Tags: pcb-design, high-speed

I was watching a teardown video for a scope and saw that the high speed input circuit has a copper frame around each input.

What is the purpose of this and what is it called?

[image]

It has a heatsink on top that makes contact on those copper traces.

It is displayed in [this video at minute 7:47.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQF4UzLPpr0&t=444s)

Comment: Was their originally a metal box screwed on top of that frame through those screw holes?

Comment: A very minimalistic anwser: This is done to keep noise from entering the circuit.

Comment: It has a heatsink on top that makes contact on those copper traces. It is displayed on the video on min 7:47

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQF4UzLPpr0&t=444s

Comment: @BasVisscher No that's not it. You cannot keep noise out with a copper pour. The technique to do that is called "via curtains" and involves placing a line of through-plated vias.

Comment: I thought those were via's? As in the gold-plated outlines. Often paired with a metal enclosure.

Comment: @BasVisscher It looks like there might be vias along them, but the picture resolution is too low to tell. The gold-plated outlines themselves are *not* vias.

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure, but the vertical portions of these metal traces seem to have a light/dark pattern that looks like a row of vias.

Comment: just some info I found about via curtains in case someone is interested after the answer from @Lundin 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/672687/119988

Comment: @BasVisscher - Hi, Re: "*A very minimalistic answer: {...}*" Please *do not* answer in comments, as explained in SE policy on the use of comments [here](/help/privileges/comment) & [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minute or so later in the video you see the back side of the heatsink that goes over the input sections:

[image]

The gold plated copper frames around each block on the PCB connect the ground of the PCB to the boxes on the back of the heatsink.

The enclosed boxes form shielding, keeping outside electrical noise from getting into the circuitry in each block.  They also keep noise from each block from causing interference in other blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The image in the JRE answer is a heat plate for conduction cooling.  In some applications, mostly military in my experience, blowing cooling air across the electronics is not an option.  Reasons can be mechanical rigidity and protection, electronic security, a corrosive environment, etc.  You can see the ends of cooling fins across the top of the plate.  They are more clear at 4:32 in the video.

Conduction cooling is much more complex and expensive to both design and manufacture.  The good news is that once you are committed to it, the heat plate can have all kinds of little super-shielded pockets.

Attaching a large heatsink to a small surface mount chip always is a risky thing to do.  The heatsink can act as a force multiplier, turning a small bump into a removed part.  Add in the fact that portable test equipment gets lots of not-small bumps, and a die-cast heat spreader makes sense.  Working with the vent pattern in the enclosure design, they are getting a ton of cooling out of a very small fan.